# saving an aoctool figure in matlab

Tags: matlab, figure

I am using the ancova tool in matlab (aoctool) and I want to save the output graph.
the problem is, I can only save it manually via the editor GUI, and not by the code itself.
(when I'm trying to save with the saveas function, it just saves an empty figure)
I'm also unable to add axis labels etc.
it seems that the problem is that the thing I want to save is not defined as a figure but as
handle, or uifigure. I was unable to overcome this problem however...

Thanks in advance!
Assaf

Answer (score 0):

The exportapp() function (introduced in Matlab 2020b) can export an image of uifigure-based apps.  You might see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Actually it doesn't work. It sends the following error massage: 'Error using exportapp
Operands to the logical and (&&) and or (||) operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.' Or, when we try a different command, we got 'Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line/horzcat
Conversion to matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line from cell is not possible.'

Comment: maybe the output of aoctool is not a uifigure? anyway, exportgraphics didn't work either... thanks in advance!